# Fortran Program Crashes when running

Tags: crash, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I'm a starter in Fortran, using it to solve mathematical models in economics. 
I wrote a program (below) that is crashing when running. Windows show that message of error and nothing seems to happen. I haven't got a clue of what may be wrong, I already debugged it and it does not show any error message on the build log.
I am using gfortran.

```
 !Value function iteration program with matrices, based on the matlab   similar code
 program valuefuncmat
 implicit none
 integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision
 integer,parameter::lower=0,upper=50 !lower and upper bounds on capital grid (lower = b in the model)
 real(dp),parameter::hex1=.01,hex2=.1 !steps on capital grid, finer on low levels of capital
  integer::i,j !loop counters
  integer,parameter::sze1=((15-lower)/hex1)+1,sze2=( ((upper-15)/hex2)+1)
  integer,parameter::sze=sze1+sze2
 real(dp)::alinha1(sze1),alinha2(sze2),agrid(sze)
 11 format(i5)
 12 format(f35.10)
 interface !interface of the functions used
 function kron(A,B)
    implicit none
    integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision
     real(dp),dimension(:,:), intent(in)::A,B !dummy arguments
     real(dp),dimension(size(A,1)*size(B,1),size(A,2)*size(B,2))::kron
     end function kron

 function repvec(A,n)
implicit none
integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision, not essencial in the code
real(dp),dimension(:), intent(in)::A
integer::n
real(dp),dimension(n,size(A))::repvec
end function repvec

 function repmat(A,n)
implicit none
integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision, not essencial in the code
real(dp),dimension(:,:), intent(in)::A
integer::n
real(dp),dimension(size(A)*n,size(A))::repmat
end function repmat

function kronvec(A,V)
implicit none
integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision, not essencial in the code
 real(dp),dimension(:,:),intent(in)::A
integer,dimension(:),intent(in)::V
real(dp),dimension(size(A,1)*size(V),size(A,2))::kronvec
end function kronvec

function kronvec2(A,V)
implicit none
integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision, not essencial in the code
integer,dimension(:,:),intent(in)::A
real(dp),dimension(:),intent(in)::V
real(dp),dimension(size(A,1)*size(V),size(A,2))::kronvec2
end function kronvec2

     end interface

    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Markov Matrix and Productivity Grid!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
real(dp), dimension(3,3), parameter::P=reshape((/ .91,.08,.01,.13,.82,.05,.005,.07,.925 /),(/3,3/),(/.0/),(/2,1/)) !markov matrix
 real(dp), dimension(3), parameter::theta_grid=(/ .1,.5,1.0 /) !the grid of productivity
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

 real(dp),parameter::A=1.0,alpha=.25,beta=.98 !Parameters of Functional Forms

real(dp),parameter::r=0.05,w=1.0,T=1.0 !Parameters for testing the value   function iteration
 integer,parameter::y=1
 real(dp),dimension(size(theta_grid),size(agrid))::vIN=.0,vOUT=1.0,apol
 real(dp)::transf(size(theta_grid)*size(agrid),size(agrid)),amatrix(size(agrid),size(agrid))
real(dp)::C(size(agrid)*size(theta_grid),size(agrid))
 real(dp)::Rzao(size(agrid)*size(theta_grid),size(agrid)),tvOUT(size(theta_grid)*size(agrid))
    integer::indexa(size(theta_grid)*size(agrid)),um(size(agrid))=1,onesm(size(theta_grid))=1,umzao(size(agrid),size(agrid))=1
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!initializing the capital grid!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    do i=1,sze1
    alinha1(i)=lower+(i-1)*hex1
    end do
do i=1,sze2
        alinha2(i)=alinha1((sze1))+hex2 +(i-1)*hex2
    end do

agrid(:sze1)=alinha1
agrid(sze1+1:sze)=alinha2

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 !!!!!!!!!!!Beginning the actual value function iteration algorithm!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!    
transf(1:y*size(agrid),:)=T !defining the types that will receive the transfer
Amatrix=transpose(repvec((1+r)*agrid,size(agrid)))-repvec(agrid,size(agrid))  !every combination of a and a' on square matrix of rank equal to the size of   agrid
C=repmat(Amatrix,size(theta_grid))+w*kronvec2(umzao,theta_grid)+transf 
where (C<=0) C=0.00000000000000001
Rzao=log(C)
do while (maxval(abs(vIN-vOUT))>0.001)
    vIN=vOUT
    tvOUT=maxval(Rzao+beta*matmul(kronvec(P,um),vIN),dim=2)
    indexa=maxloc(Rzao+beta*matmul(kronvec(P,um),vIN),dim=2)
    vOUT=reshape(tvOUT,(/size(theta_grid),size(agrid)/),order=(/2,1/))
    end do

do i=1,size(vOUT,1)
write(*,'(20G12.4)'),vOUT(i,:)
end do


 end program
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Kronecker Product Routine!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!    
function kron(A,B)
implicit none
integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision, not essencial in the code
 real(dp),dimension(:,:), intent(in)::A,B !dummy arguments
real(dp),dimension(size(A,1)*size(B,1),size(A,2)*size(B,2))::kron !output matrix of the kronecker product
 integer::i,j !loop counters

do i=1,size(A,1)
    do j=1,size(A,2)
        kron(1+size(B,1)*(i-1):size(B,1)+size(B,1)*(i-1),1+size(B,2)*(j-1):size(B,2)+size(B,2)*(j-1))=A(i,j)*B
        end do
        end do

 end function kron
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 !!Function that calculates a kronecker product between a matrix and a vector!!!!
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Vector must be integer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
function kronvec(A,V)
     implicit none
 integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision, not essencial in the code
 real(dp),dimension(:,:),intent(in)::A
 integer,dimension(:),intent(in)::V
 real(dp),dimension(size(A,1)*size(V),size(A,2))::kronvec
 integer::i
 do i=1,size(V)
     kronvec(1+size(A,1)*(i-1):size(A,1)+size(A,1)*(i-1),:)=A*V(i)
    end do

 end function kronvec
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 !!Function that calculates a kronecker product between a matrix and a vector!!!!
  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Matrix must be integer and vector real!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 function kronvec2(A,V)
    implicit none
 integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision, not essencial in the code
 integer,dimension(:,:),intent(in)::A
real(dp),dimension(:),intent(in)::V
real(dp),dimension(size(A,1)*size(V),size(A,2))::kronvec2
 integer::i
 do i=1,size(V)
    kronvec2(1+size(A,1)*(i-1):size(A,1)+size(A,1)*(i-1),:)=A*V(i)
    end do
    end function kronvec2
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 !!!!!!!!!!!!Function that repeats a vector n times verticaly!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 function repvec(A,n)
    implicit none
     integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision, not essencial in the code
     real(dp),dimension(:), intent(in)::A
    integer::n
    real(dp),dimension(n,size(A))::repvec
    integer::i
    do i=1,n
        repvec(i,:)=A
        end do


 end function repvec
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 !!!!!!!!!!!!Function that repeats a matrix n times verticaly!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  function repmat(A,n)
     implicit none
     integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15) !double precision, not essencial in the code
     real(dp),dimension(:,:), intent(in)::A
     integer::n
     real(dp),dimension(size(A)*n,size(A))::repmat
     integer::i
     do i=1,size(A)
        repmat(1+size(A)*(i-1):size(A)+size(A)*(i-1),:)=A
        end do


 end function repmat
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to make your question better.

Comment: Try compiling with `gfortran -fcheck=bounds yourcode.f90`. The error message seems to come from the `repmat()` routine where `size(A)` is used for dimensions. But this seems to be a typo of `size(A,1)` or `size(A,2)`. Also note the upper bound of do-loop in `repmat()`, which should be probably  `n` rather than `size(A)` (according to the comment of the routine and comparison with `repvec()`).

Comment: You must add all the relevant information (at least the error message!) and try to reduce the program as much as possible before posting it here. Use `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall` when compiling for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code through the NAG Fortran Compiler (on Linux). The version you have posted doesn't compile for me:

```
> nagfor -mtrace=all -u -C=all -C=undefined valuefuncmat.f90
...
Error: valuefuncmat.f90, line 100: Syntax error
       detected at )@,
...
```

That of course is easy to rectify (i.e., change line 100 to `write(*,'(20G12.4)') vOUT(i,:)`).

With that done, recompiling and running reveals

```
> nagfor -mtrace=all -u -C=all -C=undefined valuefuncmat.f90 && ./a.out
NAG Fortran Compiler Release 6.0(Hibiya) Build 1050
Extension: valuefuncmat.f90, line 88: Line longer than 132 characters
Warning: valuefuncmat.f90, line 104: Unused local variable APOL
Questionable: valuefuncmat.f90, line 104: Variable INDEXA set but never referenced
Warning: valuefuncmat.f90, line 104: Unused local variable J
Warning: valuefuncmat.f90, line 104: Unused interface for procedure KRON
Warning: valuefuncmat.f90, line 104: Local variable ONESM is initialised but never used
Warning: valuefuncmat.f90, line 62: Unused PARAMETER A
Warning: valuefuncmat.f90, line 62: Unused PARAMETER ALPHA
[NAG Fortran Compiler normal termination, 8 warnings]
[Allocated item 1 (size 65537) = Z'2AE913113010']
[Allocated item 2 (size 65537) = Z'2AE913123030']
[Allocated item 3 (size 65537) = Z'2AE913133050']
[Allocated item 4 (size 14808) at line 88 of valuefuncmat.f90 = Z'2AE913143070']
[Allocated item 5 (size 27409608) at line 154 of valuefuncmat.f90 = Z'2AE913413010']
[Allocated item 6 (size 27409608) at line 154 of valuefuncmat.f90 = Z'2AE914E37010']
[Deallocated item 6 (size 27409608, at Z'2AE914E37010') at line 166 of valuefuncmat.f90]
[Allocated item 7 (size 27409608) at line 154 of valuefuncmat.f90 = Z'2AE914E37010']
[Allocated item 8 (size 27409608) at line 154 of valuefuncmat.f90 = Z'2AE91685B010']
[Deallocated item 8 (size 27409608, at Z'2AE91685B010') at line 166 of valuefuncmat.f90]
[Deallocated item 4 (size 14808, at Z'2AE913143070') at line 88 of valuefuncmat.f90]
[Deallocated item 5 (size 27409608, at Z'2AE913413010') at line 88 of valuefuncmat.f90]
[Deallocated item 7 (size 27409608, at Z'2AE914E37010') at line 88 of valuefuncmat.f90]
[Allocation (size 281732479017624) at line 170 of valuefuncmat.f90 failed]
Runtime Error: valuefuncmat.f90, line 170: Cannot allocate array temporary - out of memory
Program terminated by fatal error
[Deallocated item 2 (size 65537, at Z'2AE913123030')]
[Deallocated item 3 (size 65537, at Z'2AE913133050')]
[Deallocated item 1 (size 65537, at Z'2AE913113010')]
Abort (core dumped)
```

Let me highlight part of that memory-trace output:

```
[Allocation (size 281732479017624) at line 170 of valuefuncmat.f90 failed]
```

As roygvib noted in their comment, this appears to be the issue that you need to address.